# Android приложение вызывает плагин музыкального плеера при блокировке экрана

Tags: android, mediaplayer, android-mediaplayer

Есть приложение, которое нацелено на воспроизведение некоторых звуков природы. Приложение работает в фоновом режиме и при блокировке экрана. Но когда разблокировать экран, то появляется плагин плеера, с несуществующими названием и исполнителем, который ни на что не реагирует. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно убрать его.[image: Вот так оно выглядит]

Comment: Мало подробностей. Приведите фрагменты проблемного кода. Что за плагин? При текущей постановке вопроса, к сожалению, ответ может быть только один - обратиться к разработчику плагина за технической поддержкой.

Comment: Это стандартный, который музыку проигрывает.